# Migration doesn't update database

Tags: laravel, migration, laravel-5.1, laravel-migrations

I have this simple code which when I run - it does not do anything at all. When I migrate, the migration runs - I have feedback from console:
`Migrated.....`
But the database stays the same. In migrations table I see my migration, also with a correct batch.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class AddDateToProgram extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('schedules', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('day')->default('2018-05-24')->nullable();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('schedules', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropIfExists('day');
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Your other migrations are working?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir Yes, the are

Comment: What's the result of `\DB::enableQueryLog(); Schema::table(...); dd(\DB::getQueryLog());`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have different migrations, I would try to change the date of the migration that is causing troubles, by renaming the file. Or you can remove temporarily the rest of files from the migrations folder and see what happens.
But I think if it was about the date, the console would say something like 'nothing to migrate' but you can give it a try.

Hope it helps, bye.